# Can't include a VC++ 12.0 library into a Windows Phone 8.0 project

Tags: visual-c++, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to use of the [FastCV](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/add-advanced-features/computer-vision-fastcv) library on a Windows Phone 8.0 project, using Visual Studio 2013, without luck.

The package comes with the *.lib file and a `vc120.pdb` file, that is supposed to be compiled with VC++ 12.
The problem is that, although having followed the right installation procedure, the compiler prints the following error:

```
mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1700'
```

Looking into the project properties, I see that the Platform Toolset is `Windows Phone 8.0 (v110_wp80)` and I cannot change it with another value (I expected something like `v120_wp80`).

How to solve this and finally compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler version mismatch should be clear, building a Phone 8.0 project is only possible with the VS2012 tool chain.  Which is why the toolset on your project is stuck on v110_wp80.  And the library you want to use *requires* v120_wp81 since that's what the library author used.

You can only use this library if you upgrade your project to Phone 8.1.  You'd have to ask the author for a rebuild if you want to keep targeting 8.0.  That might not necessarily be simple to do, plenty of changes in 8.1

While this might sound oddly un-Microsoft like, do keep the very different phone eco-system in mind.  Phone operating system versions survive just a bit longer than the milk in your refrigerator.  Phone users keep a phone only as long as the contract last, updates are pushed automatically.  Very different from desktop users, the kind whose Windows XP version needs to pried from their cold dead fingers.  Updating your project to Phone 8.1 is a reasonable approach.

Comment: Thank you. So, in concluson, FastCV (as how it's shipped now) works only on Windows Phone 8.1. Anyway their websites named it "FastCV for Windows Phone 8"... not "8.1" :D

Comment: And sounds really strange for the fact that this library is available since months before the announcement of the WinPhone 8.1 SDK. This means they dropped the support for the 8.0 platform before the complete release of the 8.1?? Woah!